# How can I re-position a 2D texture bound to a framebuffer in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

I have two framebuffers which are currently just binding two 2D textures and then drawing them in the background of a 3D application. As the images don't fit the screen, I would like to re-position them by providing an offset of some sort but at the moment they are by default drawn from `0,0` to the provided width and height.

I am drawing them using

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, ID);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height,
    GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

If I change the srcX and srcY of the `glBlitFramebuffer` method, then it still draws from `0,0`, but crops some of the image which is not what I'm looking for. From what I have read, the `glBlitFramebuffer` copies a block of pixels rather than positioning them.

Does anyone know how I could change the draw position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I change the `srcX` and `srcY` of the `glBlitFramebuffer` method, then it still draws from 0,0, but crops some of the image which is not what I'm looking for.

Well, change `dstX` and `dstY`...

Comment: Yeah thanks, I tried this originally but it made my image disappear... I've just found out that the pixels had to match the original height and width even though the image had been moved.